# How can I use cross and pmap from purrr to perform k-fold cross-validation for multiple models?

Tags: r, purrr

I'm trying to build a cross-validation process from scratch using `tidyverse` functions, and I'm getting stuck when I try to use `cross` and `pmap` to iterate my model-fitting-and-prediction-generating function across the various combinations of iterations, folds, and models.

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do. The function works if I apply it manually (e.g., `my_function(1, 1, formula_list[[1]])`), and the various versions of `cross` I've tried all produce lists of the desired length and (I thought) structure. But when I try to apply `pmap` to that list, I get an error about "unused arguments."

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(i = rep(seq(2), each = 50),
                 k = rep(seq(5), times = 20),
                 y = rnorm(100), x1 = rnorm(100), x2 = rnorm(100))

formula_list <- list( as.formula(y ~ x1), as.formula(y ~ x1 + x2))

my_function <- function(my_i, my_k, my_formula) {

    train <- filter(df, i == my_i & k != my_k)
    test <- filter(df, i == my_i & k == my_k)

    mod <- lm(my_formula, data = train)

    test$pred <- predict(mod, newdata = test)

    return(test)

}

# this throws an error about unused arguments
crossArg <- cross3(seq(2), seq(5), formula_list)
results <- pmap(crossArg, my_function)

# this throws the same error
crossArg <- cross(list(seq(2), seq(5), formula_list))
results <- pmap(crossArg, my_function)
```

I must be missing some fundamental point about the syntax of `pmap`, but I've looked at the documentation and some online examples and am still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for -> a first shot:

```
#transforming your crossArg object into a 'simpler' list ie sort of 'flatten' it a bit
xx <- do.call(rbind, crossArgs)
#will give you this
xx
  [,1] [,2] [,3]      
 [1,] 1    1    Expression
 [2,] 2    1    Expression
 [3,] 1    2    Expression
 [4,] 2    2    Expression
 [5,] 1    3    Expression
 [6,] 2    3    Expression
...
#which you can then pmap like this 
results <- pmap(list(xx[ ,1], xx[,2], xx[ ,3]), .f = my_function)
results
[[1]]
   i k        y      x1       x2    pred
1  1 1  1.06302  1.9470 -0.13058 -0.5076
2  1 1 -0.26102  0.2096  0.64801 -0.3544
3  1 1 -1.44488  0.6056  1.13862 -0.3893
4  1 1  1.94536  0.1976 -0.10705 -0.3533
...
[[20]]
   i k       y       x1       x2      pred
1  2 5 -0.1085  0.76503  0.87501 -0.123588
2  2 5 -0.6337 -0.72294 -0.35574  0.256372
3  2 5 -0.1284  0.98152 -0.68990 -0.363973
4  2 5 -1.0502  1.03324  0.05394 -0.302769
5  2 5  1.1303  0.05811 -0.28898 -0.004556
6  2 5  0.2425 -0.56192  0.76655  0.320239
7  2 5 -0.6825  0.97010  0.51890 -0.231752
8  2 5 -0.7992  0.07324 -0.20911 -0.001270
9  2 5 -0.2876  0.87090 -0.48919 -0.304710
10 2 5 -0.1145  1.38314  1.89403 -0.227532
```

PS: really like the application of `pmap()` in that way and a great reprex you provided there to help solve ...

Comment: Ahhh, okay. We can make this a bit cleaner with the `cross_df` function in the first step and then `with` in the second -- so, `crossArg <- cross_df(list(i = seq(2), k = seq(5), model = formula_list))` followed by `results <- pmap(with(crossArg, list(i, k, model)), my_function)` -- but you got me over the hump, thank you!